# How to add a namespace to an XML attribute using XmlSlurper (Apache Groovy)?

Tags: groovy, grails, xml-namespaces, xml-attribute, xmlslurper

I'm iterating through the child elements of a flattish XML, and adding a certain attribute for elements that are empty.

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlSlurper

def xmlTxt = '''<root>
              <node>
                    <element/>
                    <element/>
                  </node>
            </root>'''
          
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlTxt)

xml.node.'*'.each {
    if ( it == "") {
        it.'@foo' = "bar"
    }
}
    
return XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

The result for this is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
  <node>
    <element foo="bar"/>
    <element foo="bar"/>
  </node>
</root>
```

Now, my real requirement is to change the element so that `<element xsi:nil="true"/>`, where xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

I've tried using `.declareNamespace(xsi:'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')` when creating the XmlSlurper instance, and then `it.'@xsi:nil' = 'true'` when adding the attribute, but this results in an error. Is there a quick way to accomplish this with the syntax I'm using?

Comment: Normally you'd do the following: `.declareNamespace(x: 'http://www.groovy-lang.org')` where x is the namespace name you'd use, and the URL is the value of the schema.  Declaring the namespace prefix of `xsi` is going to be problematic I think.  Have you tried to use a different prefix?

Comment: Going for [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xml-in-a/0596007647/re166.html) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best I could come up with:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlSlurper

def xmlTxt = '''
<root>
    <node>
        <element/>
        <element/>
    </node>
</root>'''

def parseSlurper( text ) {
    def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)

    xml.node.'*'.replaceNode {
        element('xsi:nil': true, "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
    }
    
    // this should work, but doesn't.  But it doesn't throw an error either.
    // xml.node.'*'.each {
    //     it.'@xsi:nil' = true
    //     it.'xmlns:xsi' = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    // }
    
    return xml
}

def parseXmlParser( text ) {
    def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(text)
    xml.node.'*'.each {
        it.replaceNode {
            element('xsi:nil': true, "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
        }
    }
    return xml
}

def xml = parseSlurper( xmlTxt )
//def xml = parseXmlParser( xmlTxt )

println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

The issue you were having was that it didn't know about the `xsi` namespace because it wasn't in your root node definition.  Using the `declareNamespace` wasn't working either since it didn't see that definition.  I suspect it was added after the parsing so it couldn't see it.  There are some mentions of this in the docs.

I tried putting the namespace definition directly in the XML:

```
def xmlTxt = '''
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <node>
        <element/>
        <element/>
    </node>
</root>'''
```

...but it still didn't seem to see it when I added the `@xsi:nil` attribute to the element.

The only thing that worked was replacing the node with a newly defined node that included the `xmlns:xsi` definition.  Otherwise it was "unbounded" and an error was thrown.

I also checked `XmlParser` in case it handled namespaces differently, but it was pretty much the same result as `XmlSlurper`.  I included the code should you want to experiment with it too.

That's about as close as I could get it.